# SharePoint 365 - only search doc library columns not within files

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I'm a software developer who was asked to help out with some Sharepoint 365 stuff.  We have several large document libraries and as you can imagine it can be difficult searching.  We have a lot of column data and these columns are the primary means of searching.  Yes, you can currently search these.  The problem is that the search feature also includes the content of the file.  We'd like to only search for the column data and find the appropriate file that way.  Is there a method to stop the search from searching within files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option is to create a new Result Source that looks only into the meta data columns you want it to be searched up on.

I would recommend you try it for one column (using the query editor) and subsequently add other fields into the query.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-result-sources-fd8d6ac6-c5d0-454d-80a9-51580902b25d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Once this is done you can modify the search webpart to look into the new result source.

Comment: I see where you are going and I've been looking into this.  However, it seems like this adds extra steps to the user.  We just want people to go to the document library and be able to search any of the metadata columns.  Really wish there was a way to just turn off searching within the word documents themselves.  Seems like it should be a simple solution.

Comment: This can still be achieved. You should drop a search box webpart on top of the library view. Then configure it to search only the library (You can exclude searching in the file content using query editor and use only MetaData in the query..

Comment: Also you can go to the library settings -> Advanced Setting to force a reindex on that library.. this will hopefully enable searching across the metadata

Comment: How would I drop a search web part in the document library page?  Using the modern UI, I feel like there are limited options.  When I go to the classic view and open the 'Library' ribbon, 'Web Parts' is disabled.

Comment: hmm.. i can't try this now... another option is to create a new page.. then add search box and then add the library webpart.

Comment: well, most importantly, what would a query look like that limited search results to metadata?

Comment: if assuming one of the metadata name is `Company`.. then the search query will be `Company:searchterm` .. similarly you should form a large query using the `OR` clause and add all metadata